# Node.js: Cannot find module react-dom/server

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-dom, react-dom-server

I'm learning React server-side rendering. Using Koa to build the server side. Follow the [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html), I installed `react` and `react-dom`:

```sh
yarn add react react-dom
```

And next in my server side entry:

```js
import Koa from 'koa'
import Router from '@koa/router'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Home from '../client/components/HomePage'

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()
const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Home)

// print logger
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await next()
  const rt = ctx.response.get('tt')
  console.log(`${ ctx.method }-${ ctx.url }-${ rt }`)
})

// set time
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const start = Date.now()
  await next()
  const interval = Date.now() - start
  ctx.set('tt', `${ interval }ms`)
})

router.get('/', ctx => {
  ctx.body = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>hello</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">${ content }</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `
})

app.use(router.routes())

app.use(async ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'koa'
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server deployed on port 3000...')
})
```

But when I tried to start my server, it just told me:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/ssr-plg/implessr/server/node_modules/react-dom/server' imported from /Users/ssr-plg/implessr/server/index.js
Did you mean to import react-dom/server.js?
```

Here is my pkg.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

You can see my whole code in this [repo](https://github.com/liyiming22/simpleSSR/blob/master/server/index.js) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've probably fixed this by now, but did you need to specify `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` when running your script?

See [Customizing ESM specifier resolution algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm)